# Nonsingularity -- Show that if $A^T$ = $-A$ , that $(I-A)$ is nonsingular.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have that $A^T$ = $-A$.  Show that $(I-A)$ is nonsingular.

I am given that I should first show that $(I-A)^T(I-A)$ is nonsingular. Expanding this equation out, I get $(I+A^TA)$, and I think this could be achieved by establishing that A is nonsingular, but I am not given that.

Is there anything here that I could use to show nonsingularity in either $(I-A)$ or $(I-A)^T(I-A)$?

Comment: That certainly isn't true in general, e.g. when $A=I$ over $GF(2)$. If you are talking about real matrices, please specify that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit :** I assume we are dealing with real matrices; if this is not the case my answer is not valid.

$$v^T(I+A^TA)v=v^Tv+(Av)^T(Av)\geq v^Tv;$$
thus $v^T(I+A^TA)v=0$ implies $v=0$, wich shows that $I+A^TA=(I-A)^T(I-A)$ is nonsingular.

Comment: @user376744 I wanted to prove that $I+A^TA$ is definite positive (and thus nonsingular), which is why I multiplied it by $v^T$ on the left and $v$ on the right. (I answered your question here rather than in your post, in case it gets deleted).

Answer (score 1):

You have a scalar product such that $\langle A(x),y\rangle =\langle x,A^T(y)\rangle$. Suppose that $A(x)=x$, we have $\langle A(x),x\rangle=\langle x,A^T(x)\rangle$ implies that $\langle x,x\rangle=\langle x,-x\rangle$ since $A^T(x)=-A(x)=-x$. This implies that $2\langle x,x\rangle=0$, so $x=0$. Thus $Ker(I-A)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $I+A^TA$ is on the right track. Try to calculate the square norm $|(I-A)x|^2$ using  your expression. Deduce that this square norm is zero iff $x=0$. And from this establish that $I-A$ must be non-singular. (I presume that you are in finite dimension, otherwise it's a bit more complicated).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can more easily show directly that $I-A$ is non-singular. Let $v\neq 0$ be a vector. Compute
$$
\langle v, (I-A)v\rangle=\|v\|^2-\langle v,Av\rangle=\|v\|^2,
$$
since $A$ is antisymmetric. It follows that $(I-A)v\neq 0$ for any non-vanishing vector $v$. Hence the matrix $I-A$ is non-singular

Answer (score 0):

Since $A^T$ and $A$ have the same eigenvalues, the eigenvalues of $A$ need to satisfy $\lambda=-\lambda$. So the only eigenvalue is $0$, even if we see $A$ as a complex matrix. It follows that the only eigenvalue of $I-A$ is $1$, and so $I-A$ is invertible.